# Mobilefirst javascript API - Plugins

Tags: javascript, plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

Where can I find the Mobilefirst API for the plugins that MF provides out-of-the-box?

I am mainly looking for the file (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)  and file transfer (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) plugin.

I don't want to add them since they have been already added and wrapped to be used in MF.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are actually referring to the implementation files of the bundled Cordova plug-ins...

You can find them in the native folder of the environment. For example for iPhone that would be: your-project\apps\your-app\iphone\native\www\default\worklight\plugins

Note that these files are pre-bundled and you cannot remove them.
What you can do instead is to edit the config.xml file (also located in the native folder) to not use the plug-ins.